# Is there any way to get PR base in GitHub Actions workflow triggered by push event?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I would like to see what files have changed in my PR (i.e. between head and merge base) in GitHub Actions workflow triggered by a `push` event.

The PR number is not available in the event context, but I can get it by comparing event's ref sha to pull request refs:

```
$ git ls-remote
85bcbcf4e37a5e56b25c3a79086bce832ef3e974    HEAD
85bcbcf4e37a5e56b25c3a79086bce832ef3e974    refs/heads/main
3a23e73b663771615266d25f7521395851b6fddb    refs/heads/mypr    <---- event ref
3a23e73b663771615266d25f7521395851b6fddb    refs/pull/1/head   <---- pr ref
058360cb3bd1ddad7428068eea092d92c6120519    refs/pull/1/merge
```

However, I don't know the base of that PR which may not be `main`. Is there a way to figure it out without using GH REST API (which would require configuring GH token in the repo secrets)?

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context - it sounds like you want `head_ref` and `base_ref`.

Comment: According to the mentioned docs, `base_ref` is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either `pull_request` or `pull_request_target` while I use `push` to run test/build on commit.

Comment: Is that a problem for you - you're asking about a PR, and it wouldn't have much meaning if you weren't. `on: pull_request:` includes when commits are pushed to a pull request, not all `push`es are PRs so that doesn't make sense as the trigger.

Comment: We usually run tests/lint/build/deploy on `push` events. I don't see from the docs how to use `pull_request` events for this purpose.

Comment: ...you use them exactly the same. See examples like https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-branches of triggering workflows on [PR events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request). Then you'll know it's a PR and will have the refs you need; `on: push:` there may be no meaningful base.

Comment: aha, so they do get triggered on push too! Do the docs mention it? Maybe I am just blind.

Comment: They can get triggered on any and all pull request events, per the link above. _"For example, if no activity types are specified, the workflow runs when a pull request is opened or reopened **or when the head branch of the pull request is updated**"_ (emphasis mine).

Comment: Ah cool, thanks! I am blind